# Socks5 proxy: Danger of MITM malicious injection wget/ httrack?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, socks5

I occasionally use *HTTrack* or *wget* on Linux to clone and archive websites for offline viewing. I use *proxychains* and a random socks5 proxy I find in those proxy lists on the Internet. The websites I clone have https and I always initiate the crawl with https://.

My concern is, if the socks5 proxy can inject or add malicious code to the traffic as he is literally the man in the middle and I'm not using a web browser to see if the certificate validation fails?

Does wget or httrack or proxychains validate the https connection and abort the connection if it gets tempered with?

Comment: You've mentioned 3 programs here (HTTrack, wget, and proxychains).  Have you looked up the documentation of any of these programs?

Comment: @Daisetsu Yes, I have. For HTTrack I haven't found any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does wget or httrack or proxychains validate the https connection and abort the connection if it gets tempered with?

`Proxychains` does not need to verify the connection since it is only forwarding data and is not involved in any TLS itself at all. Current versions of `wget` verify the certificates and there is an explicit option to switch verification off. No such options seem to exist for `HTTrack` and it is not obvious from the documentation or changelog if proper certificate validation is done.

When in doubt just try. There are sites which have explicitly invalid certificates for this purpose, see [badssl.com](https://badssl.com/).